# C++: function wont stop looping

Tags: c++

The purpose of this function is to ask the user to input a quantity to add to an order. The function will ask them to reenter info if they input a value less than 0 and exit the function if they input 0. It accepts user input if the value is a positive integer, modifies the data member, and returns true. If the user inputs 0, the function returns false. Problem is, the program never exits no matter what the user inputs. 0, a value less than 0, and a valid positive integer all cause the function to loop and ask the user to input information again. Can someone point out what is wrong with the logic within this function to explain why this would be happening?

```
 bool Order::add(std::istream& is) {
        int quantity;
        bool start = true;
        bool val = false;
        while (start = true) {
            std::cout << "Enter quantity (0 to quit): ";
            is >> quantity;
            if (quantity == 0) {
                std::cout << "**No delivery recorded!" << std::endl;
                start = false;
            }
            else if (quantity < 0) {
                std::cout << "quantity must be a positive integer" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                copies += quantity;
                start = false;
                val = true;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are always assigning true to the "start" variable:
Change the while loop (==):

```
 while (start == true) {
```

Comment: omg, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Mark that as your answer if you are satisfied!